# Vim plugin for coloring macros

Tags: vim

Is there any way to highlight defined variables or macros in Vim? Is there any plugin which does that. For example:

```
 #define MONITORING_OFF 0

 change_monitoring(MONITORING_OFF);
```

In the above example, is there any way to highlight `MONITORING_ON`?

(I am using Vim on windows with ctags enabled.)

Thanks

Comment: @Kit: hlsearch is to highlight search results. I want to use a plugin which can tell me if there is any variable which is not defined. It is painful to compile the whole thing if u forget to define a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth to mention [Easytags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) plugin that, in addition to automatic
tags file update, supports dynamic syntax highlighting of tags occurrences.

Comment: @ib: Hey, I have one more dumb question. Every new plugin comes with a same folder structure. To install the plugin, I need to copy files to vimfiles folder on windows. That is gonna cause the duplication of files between two plugins. How do u manage it?

Comment: @agent.smith:  Yes, to install a plugin conventionally, you need to copy contents of the folders making up its directory structure to the corresponding directories in your `.vim` directory (`vimfiles` on Windows).  But I would recommend using [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to simplify plugin management.